# How do I use aws-sam start-api with nodejs and pass parameters to the handler?

Tags: node.js, aws-sam

I have an inherited project which is deployed and successfully running in aws which comprises of the apigateway and nodejs lambdas.

Up to now the entire pipeline needed to run to test changes through a full deploy.  I've created the config for launch.json so I can test the lambdas through the vscode debugger which all works well.  My problem is the way in which the handler picks up the variables because it uses commonjs:

```
exports handler = async (event) => {
    const params = event.params;

    ...usage of params
}
```

I can't pass the variables to the api.  My setup is as follows.

**launch.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        "type": "aws-sam",
        "request": "direct-invoke",
        "name": "my-example:Function",
        "invokeTarget": {
            "target": "api",
            "templatePath": "template.yaml",
            "logicalId": "ApiFunction"
        },
        "lambda": {
            "runtime": "nodejs16.x"
        },
        "sam": {},
        "api": {
            "path": "/api",
            "httpMethod": "get"
        }
    ]
}
```

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ApiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Events:
        Post:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/api'
            Method: get
```

And I've tried querystring/payload in the launch config etc

Is it possible using either get or post method because I'm thinking not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `start-api` command, then it will work as a standard API. With GET requests, it is common to pass params in the path (my.domain.com/path_parameter_1/path_parameter_2&query_parameter1=value) If you are doing a POST or PUT, the data should be included in the body.

You can also use the `invoke` function and pass a json doc as the event. `sam local invoke -n function_name -e event.json`

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'm again currently looking at ````sam local start-api -t template.yaml --env-vars event.json```` but no luck.  If I get the command line event passed I'll then have to look at launch.json so it can be used in vscode